# I am confusing some assembly code about enable PE within boot/setup.s file in Linux 0.11

Tags: linux, assembly, portable-executable

Related assembly codes are located in boot/setup.s and I paste them below:

```
    mov ax,#0x0001        ! protected mode (PE) bit 
    lmsw ax               ! This is bit!
    jmpi 0,8              ! jmp offset 0 of segment 8 (cs)
```

The first two lines have made the corresponding bit changes in CR0 control register.
So,my problem is :
    When instruction **lmsw ax** is being executed, 
the ip register points to next instruction **jmpi 0,8** .
More exactly , at this point , cs:ip points to the memory location of instruction 
**jmpi 0,8** .
But after execution of instruction **lmsw ax**, the PE mechanism is enabled. 
The cs value now 
represents segment selector, but the corresponding GDT description entry is not
 prepared for it. the GDT only contains two valid entries located in 1 and 2 respectively.So, I 
 
 think the next instruction specified by cs:ip is not the instruction **jmpi 0,8**.
**cs:ip** 
 now points to an invalid memory address. The above last instruction **jmpi 0,8** which is used 
 to place the right values into cs and eip registers cannot be reached. I know I was wrong because the 
 Linux 0.11 is verifying by long term practice. Please help me point the mistakes that I make.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU doesn't look up selectors in the GDT (or LDT) every time segment register is used. It only reads the descriptor table in memory when the segment register is loaded. It then stores the information in the segment descriptor cache.The same thing happens in real mode, when a segment register is loaded with a value, that value is used to create an entry in the descriptor cache. Then whenever that segment is used, both in real and protected mode, the processor uses the values stored in the cache.

When you switch from real mode to protected mode none of the segment registers change and none of the entries in the descriptor cache change. The cache entry for the CS register remains the same as it was before, and so the CPU executes following instruction as expected. It's not until the following far jump instruction is executed that the value of the CS register changes, which then replaces the old real mode descriptor entry with a new protected mode entry.

Comment: oh,thanks very much @rossridge.In 8086,I know there is an address add unit which use segment value and offset to yield physical address.In real mode of 80286 and later,does address add unit work same like before ?  Real mode in the 80286 is to compatible the segmented address in 8086 ,but I guess now value in the segment cache which is translated from the value in cs can be added `directly`  with the offset in the instruction to yield a physical address ,obviously, the address add unit do the action but is different with that in 8086.what do you think about this ?

Comment: @newbie 8086 didn't have a selector cache. On 80826 an later real-mode segmentation is backwards compatible. When you load a segment register in real mode the entry in selector cache has it's base set to 16 times the value loaded into the segment register. So it ends up working the same way. Although when you leave protected mode and enter real-mode on the 80386 or later the selector caches also don't change. So you can have values in the selector cache that wouldn't normally be possible in real-mode.